# Show and hide components in REACT JS

Tags: reactjs

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router'
import NewBeacon from '../NewBeacon/'

class BeaconSettings extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {inputuuid: '',
    inputmajor: '' ,
    inputminor: '' ,
    inputmanufacturer: ''};
    this.handleUuid = this.handleUuid.bind(this);
    this.handleMajor = this.handleMajor.bind(this);
    this.handleMinor = this.handleMinor.bind(this);
    this.handleManufacturer = this.handleManufacturer.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.nextPage = this.nextPage.bind(this)
    this.previousPage = this.previousPage.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      page: 1
    }

    // alert("started");

}
nextPage() {
    this.setState({ page: this.state.page + 1 })
  }

  previousPage() {
    this.setState({ page: this.state.page - 1 })
  }



static contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

handleUuid(event) {

    this.setState({inputuuid: event.target.value});
  }
  handleMajor(event){
    this.setState({inputmajor: event.target.value});
  }
  handleMinor(event){
    this.setState({inputminor: event.target.value});
  }
  handleManufacturer(event){
        this.setState({inputmanufacturer: event.target.value});
  }
handleSubmit(event) {
  fetch("http://api-env.bt2qjip33m.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/v1/beacons" ,
 {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization' : 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1OGMyOTdiOWQzZWM4NjY4MDMwNDBlNjgiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImtrQGxpdGlmZXIuY29tIiwiZmlyc3ROYW1lIjoiS2lzaGxheSIsImxhc3ROYW1lIjoiS2lzaG9yZSIsImlhdCI6MTQ4OTE0NzgzM30.nHW5w3SSov8ySziblmw2VNlGI3CsZFR-v41Jeg9uBVs'
},
body: JSON.stringify({
    name: this.state.inputname,
    description: this.state.inputdescription,
    uuid:this.state.inputuuid,
    major: this.state.inputmajor,
    minor:this.state.inputminor,
    manufacturer:this.state.inputmanufacturer,
    beaconType: "type9",
    location: this.state.store,
    floor: this.state.inputfloor,
    zone: this.state.zone
})
}).then(function(response){
  if(response.ok) {
      console.log(response)
    return response;
  }
  throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
}).then(function(data) { 
  console.log(data);
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error);
});

    alert('Submitted: ' + " " + this.state.inputuuid + " " + this.state.inputmajor + " " + this.state.inputminor + " " + this.state.inputmanufacturer);
    event.preventDefault();
    this.context.router.push('/Beacons');
  }

  render() {

    const { onSubmit } = this.props
    const { page } = this.state
    
    return (<div><div>
          <div className="animated fadeIn">
            <br /><div className="card" style={{ width: 57 + '%' }}>
              <div className="card-header">
                 Beacon Settings
              </div>
              <div className="card-block">
                <div className="input-group mb-1">
                  <span className="input-group-addon"><i className="icon-user"></i></span>
                  <input type="text"  className="form-control" value={this.state.inputuuid} onChange={this.handleUuid} placeholder="UUID" />
                </div>

                <div className="input-group mb-1">
                  <span className="input-group-addon"><i className="fa fa-align-justify"></i></span>
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" value={this.state.inputmajor} onChange={this.handleMajor} placeholder="Major Number"/>
                </div>

                <div className="input-group mb-1">
                  <span className="input-group-addon"><i className="fa fa-align-justify"></i></span>
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" value={this.state.inputminor} onChange={this.handleMinor} placeholder="Minor Number"/>
                </div>

                <div className="input-group mb-1">
                  <span className="input-group-addon"><i className="fa fa-align-justify"></i></span>
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" value={this.state.inputmanufacturer} onChange={this.handleManufacturer} placeholder="Manufacturer Number"/>
                </div><center>
                <button style={{ width: 27 + '%' }} className="nav-link btn btn-block btn-success"  onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} activeClassName="active">Save</button>


                <p>asd{this.state.inputname}</p>

<Link to={'/components/tabs'} style={{ width: 27 + '%' }} className="nav-link btn btn-block btn-success" activeClassName="active">Advance Settings</Link>
</center>

            </div>
          </div>
</div></div>
      </div>
      
        
      
    )
  }
}

export default BeaconSettings;
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router'
import { Dropdown, DropdownMenu, DropdownItem, Progress } from 'reactstrap';
import Session from 'redux-react-session';
import BeaconSettings from '../BeaconSettings';
class NewBeacon extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {inputname: '',
    inputdescription: '' ,
    inputzone: '' ,
    inputstore: '' ,
    inputfloor: '',
    dropdownZone: false,
    dropdownStore: false,
    dropdownFloor: false,
    data:[
                {name:"Nikko Laus1"},
                {name:"Sam Collins"},
                {name:"Carl Smith Wesson"}
            ],
            store:[
                {name:"abcd"},
                {name:"Sam Collins"},
                {name:"Carl Smith Wesson"}   
            ],
            floor:[
                {name:"Ist"},
                {name:"IInd"},
                {name:"IIIrd"}   
            ]
    };
    
    this.handleName = this.handleName.bind(this);
    this.handleDescription = this.handleDescription.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.toggleDropdown = this.toggleDropdown.bind(this);
    // alert("hey");


  }
static contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
handleSubmit(event){

    alert('Submitted: ' + this.state.inputname + this.state.inputdescription + this.state.inputzone + this.state.inputstore + this.state.inputfloor);
    event.preventDefault();
    this.context.router.push('/components/BeaconSettings');
  }
  toggleDropdown(dropType) {
       this.setState({[dropType]: !this.state[dropType]})
  }


  handleName(event) {

    this.setState({inputname: event.target.value});
  }
  handleDescription(event){
    this.setState({inputdescription: event.target.value});
  }
  handleChange(event, type) {
    this.setState({[type]: event.target.value});  
  }

  save_data(value) {
   this.setState({inputname: event.target.value}); 

 }

  render() {
    let Zone = this.state.data.map(person =>
        {
            return <DropElement key={person.id} data={person}/>
        });

    let Store = this.state.store.map(person =>
    {
        return <DropElement key={person.id} data={person}/>
    });
    let Floor = this.state.floor.map(person =>
    {
        return <DropElement key={person.id} data={person}/>
    });
    return (<div><div>
          <div className="animated fadeIn">
            <br /><div className="card" style={{ width: 77 + '%' }}>
              <div className="card-header">
                 Create Beacon
              </div>
              <div className="card-block">
                <div className="input-group mb-1">
                  <span className="input-group-addon"><i className="icon-user"></i></span>
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" value={this.state.inputname} onChange={this.handleName} placeholder="Name" />
                </div>

                <div className="input-group mb-1">
                  <span className="input-group-addon"><i className="fa fa-align-justify"></i></span>
                  <input type="textArea" value={this.state.inputdescription} onChange={this.handleDescription} className="form-control" placeholder="Description"/>
                </div>
                <div className="card-header">
                Select a zone</div>
                <div className="card-block"><div className="px-1 row">Zone:
                <div className="px-2 mb-1">

                <Dropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownZone}  toggle={this.toggleDropdown.bind(this, 'dropdownZone')}>
                    <button type="button" value={this.state.inputzone} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'inputzone')} className="caret" 
                    onClick={this.toggleDropdown.bind(this, 'dropdownZone')} data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded={this.state.dropdownZone} >
                    Select a Zone</button>

                    <DropdownMenu>
                        {Zone}

                    </DropdownMenu>
                  </Dropdown></div></div></div>

                  <div className="card-header">
                Select a Store</div>
                <div className="card-block"><div className="px-1 row">Store:
                <div className=" px-2 mb-1">

                  <Dropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownStore}  toggle={this.toggleDropdown.bind(this, 'dropdownStore')}>
                    <button type="button" value={this.state.inputstore} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'inputstore')}  className="caret" 
                    onClick={this.toggleDropdown.bind(this, 'dropdownStore')} data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded={this.state.dropdownStore}>
                    Select a Store</button>

                    <DropdownMenu>

                     {Store}

                    </DropdownMenu>
                  </Dropdown>

                </div></div></div>
                  <div className="card-header">
                Select a floor</div>
                <div className="card-block"><div className="px-1 row">Floor:
                <div className=" px-2 mb-1">

                  <Dropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownFloor}  toggle={this.toggleDropdown.bind(this, 'dropdownFloor')}>
                    <button type="button" value={this.state.inputfloor} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'inputfloor')} 
                    onClick={this.toggleDropdown.bind(this, 'dropdownFloor')} data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded={this.state.dropdownFloor}>
                    Select a Floor</button>

                    <DropdownMenu>
                          {Floor}

                    </DropdownMenu>
                  </Dropdown></div></div></div>


                  </div>

              </div>

              </div>
            </div>

          <div className="px-2 row" style={{ width: 90 + '%' }}>
          <div><button  className="nav-link btn btn-block btn-success" onClick={this.handleSubmit} >
                Next</button>
                </div><div className="px-2"><Link to={'/components/social-buttons'} className="nav-link btn btn-block btn-danger" activeClassName="active"> Cancel</Link>
</div>
<div className="float-right"><Link to={'/components/social-buttons'} className="nav-link btn btn-block btn-success" activeClassName="active">
Default Notification
</Link></div>
</div></div>




    )
  }
}

class DropElement extends React.Component
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();
    }

    render()
    {
        return (<DropdownItem>{this.props.data.name}
                   </DropdownItem>
            );
    }
}

export default NewBeacon;
```

I am making 2 screens in react and i wanted a third screen containing these two screens in that so that on clicking the next button the first component will be hidden and the other component or page is shown to enter the details so that to send all the values to the server together

Comment: You don't seem to be using your state.page nowhere ..

PS: In BeaconSettings you seem to be overwriting your state (in the constructor)